# Data transfer Windows Embedded Compact 7 & Computer VIA USB connection

Tags: sockets, usb, windows-mobile, tcpclient, windows-embedded-compact

I made an app using the barcoding for inventory management, now i need to transfer that data to the computer. For this purpose i used TCP/IP Host client sample applications given in *windows mobile 6.5.3 SDK samples*.

When i run the application its' fine no errors, shows connected to the Host IP but no data is transferred, When i debugged there is no exception code just works fine but there is no functionality performed. My connection is USB connection. IP shown in host application is correct, my device is also having IP (check through `ipconfig`). Now when i ping my host computer from device, it is giving error

```
PING: transmit failed, error code 11010
```

Is my approach right towards this situation using this data transfer over this socket ? If yes then how can i make this connection successful ? If not what is the other solution for this data transfer from device to computer. (software on device is using SQL CE and application on computer is ASP.NET application using SQL Server database.)

I saw various similar questions about this problem but unable to find any suitable solution. PS i am new this platform of windows mobile/embedded

Comment: error code 11010 represents lack of resources which i guess my network was not configured somehow. How can i fix this error

Comment: Error code 11010, if it is a Winsock error, means `WSA_QOS_ADMISSION_FAILURE`, which doesn't seem like it's applicable here.  Apparently the ICMP API in Windows can return `IP_REQ_TIMED_OUT`, which is also equal to 11010.  It seems like that is what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

> If not what is the other solution for this data transfer from device
>   to computer. (software on device is using SQL CE and application on
>   computer is ASP.NET application using SQL Server database.)

These are some common solutions for client/server communications on Windows Mobile:

1. Use [RAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa920177.aspx) or [RAPI2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920150.aspx) to communicate with the mobile device and host PC using the USB ActiveSync/Windows Mobile Device Center connection.  You could use this option to export a CSV file from the mobile device to the host PC.  Then you can import the CSV file into the host database. Requires physical access to host PC via USB.
2. Call a web service to transmit the data to the server. You can write a simple RESTful web service using ASP.NET Web API.  If you're using C++ you can use [WinInet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa917828.aspx) API, but it's kind of painful.  If you're using C# then you have built-in support and it's not an issue.
3. Use [SQL CE Replication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms152568(v=SQL.105).aspx).

Comment: After no hope I am currently using https://rapi.codeplex.com/ which is based on `RAPI` but i was hoping to use something independent. RAPI depends on **ActiveSync/Windows Mobile Device Center connection** . This application will be used in a environment where network might not be available so can't use  RESTful web service. This was my first choice off course.

Comment: I am currently copying my SDF file, doing the stuff i and writing it back in device, i was wondering if this is a right thing to do ? Importing exporting CSVs was kind of exhausting as i have to delete the data which is synced.

Comment: It's not ideal but it should get the job done.  I ended up using a solution like this for a customer because they had a requirement to not depend on an Internet connection.

Comment: Hmmm . . . Somewhat same situation here. So no solutiion except RAPI ?

Comment: It's the simplest solution I found for this problem that works.  There is also ActiveSync/Windows Mobile Device Center Desktop Passthrough (DTPT).  It's supposed to share the host PC Internet connection with the device.  I've not used it personally so I can't recommend for or against it.  It's my understanding if you could get that working you could call web service calls without an Internet connection but only between the host PC and the device.

Comment: It turns out that ASP.NET dosen't supports SQL Server CE 3.5 database and SQL Server CE 4.0 is not supported by Windows Mobile, Windows Phone or for Windows CE devices, Now only option left is to use CSV files :( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx